# pass in Bootstrap data-id with javascript of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I maybe totally wrong but I'm using the save modal form to select US States and when a value is selected it fills in the value in the calling form.  I need to use the Pop-up on many different forms so I need to know what form is calling the US States popup modal.  I think I read somewhere but can't located to use the data-id value and set that when I call open but I can seem to find how to set the value or to get the value.

Any help is appreciated

If there is a better way I'm open to suggestions.

I'm using Bootstrap 3+

Comment: you'll need to write custom modal triggers if you want that level of control.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on(
  'show.bs.modal', 
  function(){ 
    console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  }
);
```

found in bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events

Comment: How can I set the data-id attr when I try to use     $('#states-modal').attr('data-id').val('formName'); It throws an error

Comment: ``$('#states-modal').attr('data-attr', 'your-value').val('fromName');``